# Setting up the Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

[Here is the Screenshot] While setting up the Android studio, I can't run even the simple Application. when I click the run it shows to select the target device. but for devices, I can't select any device. It is still loading. What would be the reason?

Is there any version issue or Windows issue? I'm using Windows 11 and android-studio-2020.3.1.24-windows

Answer (score 0):

There may be a problem  with Windows 11. to solve that issue follow the steps
Go to the android studio app
Right-click the app
Go to Properties
Go to compatibility
Check the Run this program in compatibility mode
Select windows version 10 or 8 or 7
Then apply and ok

After these changes start the Android Studio App

Comment: Would be nicer with a better formatted answer, and maybe with a screenshot